# Object Detection TF2

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using an API to obtain a dataset of images to train an object detection model. Each image class has its own directory, for example, the "bitcoin" class, and each image within the directory is named "bitcoin_1.png," "bitcoin_2.png," etc. The images I obtain from the API are already cropped and only include the object of interest. What preprocessing do I need to perform on these images to make them a valid dataset , do I only need to convert them to a TFRecord?